# missing column ID in a matrix leads to an error message

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices:

m1:

```
 ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5

row1 1   2   3   3   1   

row2 2   3   1   2   3
```

m2:

```
     ID1 ID2 " " ID3 ID4 ID5

row1 1   3   2   1   2   3
```

In `m2` there is a column without a column header ID and this missing ID corresponds to a value of `2` in `row1`.

My question is how can I delete the entire column with the missing column id.

If I do not exclude the column with missing id, I get an error message

> non-numeric argument to binary operator

when I try to apply the following function:

```
m3<-t(t(m1)*m2[2, ]
```

Comment: `m2[,grepl('ID', colnames(m2))]`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thanks v much. In case the ids did not follow a pattern and were ID1 ID2 VAR3 " " 4_VAR ID5, instead of ID1 ID2 " " ID3 ID4 ID5 (as in the above example), then how would you delete the unwanted column in such a scenario.

Comment: use `m2[,!grepl('^ $', colnames(m2))]` if you want to delete one spaced named columns.